# How to retrieve input data from django-generated forms

Tags: python, json, django

So I have this code in one of my templates in a django app:

```
{% for key, value in Monday.items %}
    {% for k, v in value.items %}
        {% if k == 'song'%}
            <form>
                {{ key }} : 
                <input type="text" value="{{ v }}"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="change"/><br>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The page looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpDud.png

"Monday" is a dict passed in as the context when the template is rendered. The dict is generated with data from a json file. I want to be able to retrieve the contents of the text field when the "change" button is pressed so that I can update the relevant json values. I know how to rewrite values to the json file once I have the new values, but I don't know how to get those changed values.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<input type="text" value="{{ v }}"/> 
<input type="submit" value="change" class="change_btn"/><br>
```

js

```
$('.change_btn').on('click', function(){
    var changed_txt = $(this).prev().val();
    // send this changed text to backend via ajax to update your monday? 

})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, do you know of a python-y solution that I could use?